# dumping PDF document ( *.pdf) to Text?

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-2010

I got some great help on here (section of code) for dumping a word doc to text. Now, i am
looking for help in dumping a PDF Document ( *.pdf) to Text? I am using Delphi 2010. I would prefer a non-component, non-Active-X, solution....as this code will be incorporated into my own component.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDFtext](http://www.is-soft.de/pdfanalyzer/prod14.htm) can do it. You'll have to pay $57 and deploy additional dll, though.

Comment: This may be an acceptable answer, but i will wait alittle while longer to see if someone else has a free option. Thank You.

Comment: I should maybe add that I'm using PDFtext and works fine for me.

Comment: I guess this is my only option!

Answer (score 6):

You've got two free options, as far as I can tell.

First, there is a command line tool in the xpf package freely available from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf

Then, another command line tool in the http://mupdf.com project

Both can be called easily from Delphi. I used the pdftotext.exe file from xpdf without any problem.

Comment: Thanks, i will check this out and get back to you!

Comment: I downloaded both. The XPDF looks promising, but i can't seem to figure out how the config file works. I looked at the Sample xpdfrc file and i dont see anything in there that shows the configuration for input or output file.  The mudpf tool looks to me like it came with a gui app and some command line tools ( none of which are pdfshow, pdfextract, pdfinfo - which the web page described) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [QuickPDF](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/) library to find text within PDF files.  I use the function

```
GetPageText(ExtractOptions: Integer): string;
```

to get the text from each page so that it can be searched.
If you use 0 for ExtractOptions, it will return the text in readable format.  It's not free, but both the library and the documentation are very good.  Also, a very active community blog is hosted at their website.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to mention in my question, but i was hoping for a Free or Opensource Solution. I will check this out surely if i dont find a free or onesource solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt try it but [TSMPDFReader](http://www.scalabium.com/msword/) seems to be OK for you : no DLL, no Activex no external component. 
Not free but 35 € is not too expensive.

I work with other components from Scalabium : great support.